# How is this a use question and not design?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

[Qi Charging transmitter types](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/511674/17178) was closed as a usage question when it's about using a semiconductor reference module in a design. Wouldnt that make any question on why a given electrical engineering component or circuit isn't working as expected off topic?

Comment: Is a Qi charger consumer or engineering equipment?

Comment: Probably less contentious to let the community close it.  It's not important enough for mod nuking.

Comment: @voltage is a power supply consumer or engineering equipment. Is a SOC a consumer or engineering equipment? Is a motor a consumer or engineering equipment. Is an LCD, radio, esp82, arduino, etc etc. It's not an off the shelf consumer product.

Comment: It's an electronics module used in a greater context.

Comment: @scott there aren't many people contributing to the close vote que, in a day it can accumulate up to 100 questions, I'm trying to stay ahead of the deluge and clean up the que before it gets out of hand, I would encourage everyone to help with the moderation of the que

Comment: Is the OP asking how to use a charger or design one?

Comment: `I am working on a Qi Transmitter project` and `I read the technical specs` and `transmitter design`. It's part of a larger design.

Comment: @voltage that's not how close votes are supposed to work. You are bypassing the system by mod closing them as a Literal ban hammer move. Close vote queue isnt there to be emptied immediately. What's the point of a community based 5 votes to close if you single handedly decide everything should be closed.

Comment: @VoltageSpike  -  I commiserate.  feel free to metapost for help on the queue.

Comment: @passerby I will open the question then

Comment: It's a usage question becuase it has all of the issues of a usage question: it's literally about using something, for which no documentation is presented, and then it goes on to talk about what solutions could be purchased.  This isn't design at all, but usage & purchasing.  Just because *Passerby* might approach this need as a design problem doesn't change fact that the *asker* is not approaching it as one.